# "everybody sing" vs "everybody sings"

Tags: expressions, grammatical-number

I have been told 'everybody' is singular. However, there was a film named "Everybody Sing".

What are the differences between "everybody sing" and "everybody sings"?

Which is correct? the former, the latter, or the both?

Which is more natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean different things.

"Everybody sing." by itself would be a command telling everyone to sing.

"Everybody sings." is a statement that everyone sings.

Comment: Compare: 'John - sing!' with 'John sings' (and remember that titles take liberties with grammar, so the dash, colon or comma could be omitted - though I bet they left the exclamation mark in). I wouldn't say that 'everybody is singular' - we'd say 'all (the people) are here' - but it does take singular agreement (ie a singular verb-form).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the film in question but here is how I would differentiate between them.

You would use *sings* in standard sentences of subject + verb:

> Everybody sings in the bath.
>
> Everybody sings when they are happy.

*Everybody sing* is a command or instruction eg if you are leading a choir.

*Everybody* is to get everyone's attention, the command is *Sing*

> "Ok everybody, stop talking. John, do the first verse solo, then
>   everybody sing!"